# OpenGL Draw only some indexes from vertex array

Tags: c++, opengl

how can I only draw selected indices from vertex array in OpenGL?

For instance, I am drawing my vertices like points, with some variable `m_pointCloud` containing my point cloud vertices (points):

```
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glPointSize(m_pointSize * point_scale);

glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    static_cast<GLsizei>(sizeof(DensePoint)), &((*m_pointCloud)[0].r));
// glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,
//  static_cast<GLsizei>(sizeof(DensePoint)), &((*m_pointCloud)[0].n_x));
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,
    static_cast<GLsizei>(sizeof(DensePoint)), &((*m_pointCloud)[0].x));

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, static_cast<GLsizei>(m_pointCloud->size()) - 1);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

But I have some `std::vector<size_t> indices` containing the indices from `m_pointCloud` that I want to draw. How is this done?

Comment: Use an index buffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) and/or draw by using glDrawElement.

Comment: But can it be done with `glVertexPointer` usage? Could you provide some example maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of glDrawArrays, use [glDrawElements](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml).

For example:

```
std::vector<GLuint> indices;

// populate vertices

glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, reinterpret_cast<void*>(indices.data()));
```

Note also that you cannot use `size_t` as an index type as OpenGL only allows 8, 16 and 32-bit indices.

Comment: and how do I specify vertice colors? because I want to use the original colors from array but I also want to draw the remaining points (not included in índices vector) with red color

Comment: Like with most things in OpenGL, there's multiple ways to accomplish this. The easiest way (that doesn't involve writing shaders or storing lots of extra data) might be to draw the colored points as normal, disable the color pointer array, set glColor to red, then redraw the remaining points.